# Sub Query SQL - select

Tags: sql, subquery

Question :Write the SQL statement to retrieve first and last name of guests who have never
reserved a family (‘F’) room. You must use a subquery. (outcome = 4 rows)

My code:

```
select firstname,lastname
from guest, reservation
where reservation.guestid=guest.guestid
and roomnum in  
(select roomnum
from room
where roomtype =  'f');
```

I get 26 rows. 
I think I am doing the sub query wrong.

Comment: Could you give an example of your dataset?

Comment: Have you covered the EXISTS() function yet in your class?

Comment: No we have not , only subqueries and joins so far Thankyou for the help it helped , I will redo it with how we are taught in my class but I seen my mistake and understood the way you did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid the JOIN entirely, and just use a sub-query:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname
FROM guest
WHERE guestid NOT IN (
  SELECT guestid
  FROM reservation, room
  WHERE reservation.roomnum=room.roomnum
  AND roomtype='f'
)
```

This avoids getting the same guest multiple times if they have multiple reservations.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what Is asked of us!

Answer (score 0):

Er, who is teaching you? Comma-separated joins where replaced by explicit joins over twenty years ago and should not be used anymore. (Use `from guest join reservation on reservation.guestid = guest.guestid` instead.)

As to your problem: You want to select names from *guest*. No join here. Then you want to make sure no F reservation *exists* for a guest. A NOT EXISTS clause or usually a bit simpler: a NOT IN clause.

```
select firstname, lastname
from guest
where guestid not in
(
  select guestid
  from reservation
  where roomnum in 
  (
    select roomnum
    from room
    where roomtype =  'F'
  )
);
```

Comment: Don't really need the second subquery do you?   A join of reservation and room gets the same result.

Comment: @Tab Alleman: Yes that's true; you don't need the subquery, you can use a join. But I could also argue: you don't need the join, you can use a subquery. One is not better than the other. I like a subquery better here. I say: "Find reservations where the room is an F room". You say: "Find out for every reservation what room type it is, then only keep room type F". Both approaches are correct. I find mine more intuitive and straight-forward. But that may be a matter of personal preference in the end.

Comment: Very Helpful! Thank you! I will redo it to how my class requires it to be done but your help definitely solved it. BTW - Although a second subquery was what I thought was right it does have to be a a join for this part.

Comment: I am glad this helped. I don't know what you mean with "it does have to be a a join for this part" though. Are you required to have at least one join in your query? You join when you want results from both tables, but here you only want results from one table, namely the guestid from table reservation. Criteria (certain room numbers in your case) belong in the WHERE clause. That's a rule of thumb only, because you can also use a join here - especially as there is only one roomnum per reservation, so you don't even create unnecessary records in your intermediate result.

Answer (score 0):

You need the list of guest who never made a family type reservation (First sub query takes care of it) and also you need to remove guests who have never made a reservation too (second sub query would handle it).

```
SELECT firstname, lastname
FROM guest
WHERE guestid NOT IN (
  SELECT guestid
  FROM reservation, room
  WHERE reservation.roomnum=room.roomnum
  AND roomtype='f'
) and guestid in 
(
  SELECT guestid
  FROM reservation, room
  WHERE reservation.roomnum=room.roomnum
)
```

Check out the SQL Fiddle created to try out. 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4221/2/0

Comment: Thank you for the link will definitely use it for future purposes! I had to tweak the code a bit to fit the requirements of the assignment but otherwise it was very helpful , thank you!

Comment: It was not a requirement that the guests to find made at least one reservation, so the second subquery is not needed. Even if it were, there is no feed for a join with table room in it, as all the information is present in table reservation already. And then you shouldn't encourage a join syntax that's been out-dated for more than twenty years now (as of SQL-92).